# Annotation not working in osgi bundle

Tags: java, annotations, osgi, osgi-bundle, blueprint-osgi

I have bundle which is having annotations in java file (Annotations like @jsonIgnore etc), and output of bundle is json String. but after deploying bundle output json string i am getting all those attributes on which i have applied @jsonIgnore. it should not come ,is there any thing i need to do Annotation usage in osgi bundle.

```
@JsonIgnore
public String getSurveys() {
    return surveys;
}


public void setSurveys(String str) {
    this.surveys = str;
}
```

but in Json String i am getting surveys field, that should not come

Comment: Annotations never "work"... they are just annotations! What you seem to be saying is that whatever JSON serialiser you are using is not working. You should provide some more information on that.

Comment: @NeilBartlett : yes you are correct json serializer is not working, i need to know the reason why it is not working, 
while generating json string, it should not include all those attributes for which i have used jsonIgnore.

Comment: So... you want us to just guess which JSON serializer you are using?